# Facebook App review for B2B web based solutions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a ticketing solution that is configured to one FB page, from that FB page my application can read the post and comments ad create them as tickets. In a ticket I can post a comment back to the FB page.

My issue is this is not an app also users of the ticketing solution which are agents they dont login through FB, app has its own login module.

So how can I get my web based application reviewed when I cant create any Test Users as no can login with a FB account into the app.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Gary

According to the documentation of the [test-users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/) in the facebook developer there are some important things to note while creating the test users

- They are invisible to the real accounts.
- Test users are exempt from spam or fake detection systems so you can test the app without getting disabled

Once you add a new test user you will be prompted with some of the options

**Number to Create** determines how many individual test user accounts are created. If you want to create more in bulk, you should use the Graph API instead.

**Authorize Test Users** for This App determines whether each newly created test account will already have logged into the app (using Facebook Login), without having to accept the Login Dialog, etc.

**Enable Ticker** allows anyone logged into each of these test accounts to view the ticker for that user.

**Under 18** determines whether the accounts will have an age under 18 years old, which is useful for testing demographic restrictions. You can still change this age later manually by logging into the test account.

Language chooses the locale that the test accounts will use to view Facebook.

This answers your question

//Full attribution goes to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/)